# Как вы отделяете код от представления?

Tags: php, css

Как вы отделяете код от представления (например от html) в больших проектах?

Шаблонизаторы конечно могут быть удобны, но по сути представляют из себя всего лишь обертку над php, поэтому не пишите здесь о шаблонизаторах, это не разделение, а лишний псевдокод правила поведения которого (если это поддерживает условия) дополнительно нужно изучать.

Лично я формирую массивы данных в контроллере и через функцию произвожу подключение .tpl файла, в функцию передаю массив данных, а функция возвращает буферизированное решение этого файла. В самом файле нужный контент (html, xml, json...) с php вставками переменных вроде:

`<?php echo isset($data['var']) && $data['var'] ? $data['var'] : ''; ?>`

У меня вопрос к такому подходу только один. Когда возникает потребность вставки в шаблон других шаблонов (например 10 коротких новостей в шаблон главной страницы), приходится составлять в контроллере каждый такой эллемент и передавать его в основной.

Допустимо ли с точки зрения идеологии MVC в таких файлах шаблонов производить подключение шаблонов напрямую? Не важно в цикле или чем-нибудь вроде `View::renderMatch('short/article.php', $data['articles_data_array'])`

Не затрагивает ли такой сбор шаблона обязанности контроллера? Вопрос не обязательный для ответа.

**Главный вопрос** в том, как вы отделяете в своих проектах логику представления, от шаблона и делаете ли это вообще. Было бы интересно почитать как это делают другие люди.

Comment: js с ajax-ом вам в помощь

Answer (score 3):

Другие люди используют шаблонные движки. Хоть Smarty, хоть [Liquid](https://github.com/kalimatas/php-liquid), хоть [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/), хоть Twig или Blade.

Все сколько-нибудь серьёзные шаблонные движки умеют подключать шаблоны внутри шаблонов, наследовать шаблоны от других, и так далее. В общем случае вы можете ожидать примерно одного уровня возможностей. Выбор шаблонного движка - дело вкуса, предпочтений и традиций в вашей среде (разработчики под Laravel пользуются Blade, а Symfony - Twig).

Бонусом к использованию шаблонного движка вы получите и защиту от случайных XSS, и более чистый код без бесконечных проверок `isset()`, и возможность делегировать работу над вёрсткой страниц посторонним.

Шаблонные движки приводят к некоторому замедлению открытия страниц при первой компиляции шаблона, но эта проблема решается массовой компиляцией шаблонов при деплое.

Comment: У меня всегда шаблонизаторы ассоциируются с x: `{name} хочет сказать: {phrase}` y: `Я дружу с {name2}. Кстати, мой тег {name}, он не должен быть заменен.` Если name - Вася, а name2 - Петя и phrase - это второй текст, то получился бы текст: `Вася хочет сказать: Я дружу с Петя. Кстати, мой тег Вася, он не должен быть заменен.`. Все из-за того что обычно шаблонизаторы подразумевают str_replace, который во второй итерации замены - видит "тэг" и меняет его, хотя это было не нужно. Но вопрос конечно же не об этом. Получается если в шаблон `news` нужно было бы вставить 10 шаблонов `short_article`...

Comment: Вы не поверите, но [в типичном шаблонизаторе есть циклы](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/iteration-tags).

Comment: То вы бы составили массив данных в контроллере и передали бы их в `main`, а задача `main` была бы перебрать массив `$data['articles']` и соответственно 10 раз подключить шаблон `short_article`?

Comment: Понятное дело что они есть. Отойдем от темы шаблонов. Чья задача по вашему генерировать строку из 10 шаблонов `short_article`? Метода представления в контроллере, ответ которого потом передается в `main` или шаблона `news`?

Comment: Если вы много где показываете список новостей, то это дело отдельного шаблона.

Comment: Допустим это шаблон `article_list`. Вопрос остается. У вас есть данные `['page_title'=>...,'article_list'=>['title'=>...,'text'=>...],['title'=>...,'text'=>...]...,'pade_description'=>...]`. Вопрос в том, как бы вы их отрисовывали? Вы могли бы в контроллере собрать из элемента `article_list` строку используя шаблон `short_article`. А потом передать этот же массив данных, но с элементом `article_list` замененным на эту самую решенную строку в шаблон `main`, где данные просто отобразились бы. А могли бы передать данные сразу в `main`, в котором собрался бы `short_article`

Answer (score 1):

Обычно есть контроллеры, которые собирают данные для представления (виды), и, если надо, запускают валидацию введенных данных. Модели содержат логику по получению данных из БД и т.д., контроллеры используют методы моделей и не лезут в БД самостоятельно.

Виды занимаются только формированием окончательного HTML. 
Никакой сложной логики, никакого обращения в БД.

Как правило есть привилегированный вид - макет (layout), который содержит общий код для ХТМЛ страниц и в определенное место которого вставляется результат обработки вида.

Виды могут вызвать вставку других видов - небольшие общие куски для нескольких страниц.

Файлы видов располагаются в отдельной директории, в подпапке с именем контроллера и их имя соответствует имени метода контроллера.